# Differences between 'plead' and 'beg'

Tags: word-choice

> Fearing for his life, he **pleaded/begged** the mugger for mercy.

Which verb is correct here and why?

As I looked up in the dictionary, I found both 'plead for mercy' and 'beg for mercy'. Therefore, I think both words have similar meaning.

Comment: Are you asking about which one is grammatical as written, or which one better fits the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 10):

> Fearing for his life, he pleaded/begged the mugger for mercy.

Begged is the correct term here grammatically. Although you can use both to convey the same meaning. For example:

> Fearing for his life, he begged the mugger for mercy.

and

> Fearing for his life, he pleaded **with** the mugger for mercy.

both convey the same meaning.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that some verbs allow a direct object and others don't.

*beg* allows direct objects

He begged the mugger for mercy.

*plead* just doesn't work with human direct objects these days. Note that "plead" has two past tense forms, "pleaded" and "pled.")

"Plead" works with things like

"He pled (or: pleaded) insanity/guilty/not guilty" in a legal context.

So "He pled/pleaded the mugger for mercy" doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

> Fearing for his life, he **pleaded** to the mugger for mercy.

*plead* is the best choice based on the definition, [***plead***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/plead):

> 2) to make an earnest appeal; supplicate; beg   ⇒ *"to plead for mercy"*

In this situation "earnest appeal" certainly applies.
*plead* generally is used in negative situations, such as legal matters where you are defending your self or beliefs.

In the case of [***beg***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/beg) you can't find a similar definition:

> *transitive verb*
>   1) to ask for as charity or as a gift   ⇒ "he begged a dime"
>   2) to ask for earnestly as a kindness or favor
>   *intransitive verb*
>   3) to ask for alms; be a beggar
>   4) to ask humbly; entreat

*beg* is more of a favor for your benefit in a positive setting.
However in general usage probably both would come up.

Comment: _"he pleaded the mugger...."_ is not idiomatic English.  Pleaded does not take a direct object.

Comment: @Adam So it is. I edited my answer. Or perhaps "he pleaded for mercy from the mugger".

Comment: @user3169 I am actually confused by your reply to Adam. "So it is" shows agreement, but Adam says that phrase is _not_ idiomatic English. So are you agreeing with Adam or not? Your new edit seems to be based on Adam's suggestion.

Comment: @EddieKal Yes, I was agreeing with Adam. I meant "You are right."